# Undocumented API client / wrapper in Python

Tags: python, api, http, wrapper, client

Got the go ahead to make an API wrapper for an undocumented web API.
Hoping to get some feedback on my code and design choice.

I've been going back and forth and haven't been able to really feel satisfied with any of my design choices.

There's a lot of placeholders but I think the base of what I am going for should make sense, at this point it would be a matter of adding the endpoints and do the error catching if I were to continue with it as-is.

Tips, alternative design choices, really anything is welcome and I appreciate it all.

```
from uuid import uuid4
from time import strftime, gmtime

from hashlib import md5

import requests


class Wrapper:

    endpoints = ['sign_in', 'sign_up']

    def __init__(self):
        # Details
        self.prv_key = ''  # private_key
        self.pub_key = ''  # token
        self.member_id = 0
        self.device_id = uuid4()

        # 'X-Device' header
        self.device_header = \
            '{0},{1},{2}:{2}'.format('android', self.device_id, '845')

    @property
    def auth_token(self):
        auth_token = ','.join((

            # MD5 of auth and time stamp
            md5(self.prv_key + self.pub_key).hexdigest(),
            md5(strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M,mobile', gmtime())).hexdigest(),

            # Member ID can't be int(0)
            str(self.member_id or '')

        ))

        return auth_token

    def request(self, url, method, **kwargs):
        # Default headers
        kwargs['headers'] = {
            'X-AuthToken':     self.auth_token,
            'X-Device':        self.device_header,
            'Accept':          'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
            'User-Agent':      'okhttp/3.6.0'
        }
        # Proxy settings
        kwargs['proxies'] = {
            'https':           '192.168.178.27:8085',  # TODO: DEBUG
            'http':            '192.168.178.27:8085'   # TODO: DEBUG
        }
        # SSL verification
        kwargs['verify'] = False  # TODO: DEBUG

        r = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)

        # TODO: CATCH ERRORS
        # TODO: CORRECT RESPONSE
        response = r.content

        return response

    def sign_in(self):
        return self.request('http://httpbin.org/get', 'GET')  # TODO: DEBUG

    def sign_up(self):
        return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = Wrapper()
    print test.sign_in()
```